# Calling non-static methods in java

Tags: java, methods, static

I have question about static methods in Java. Why is that I can call a non-static method in another non-static method without specifying an instance of the class. For example if I have two non-static methods foo1() and foo2(), I can say foo2(){ foo() }. I can't do this in a static method. For example static void foo3(){ foo() }, this would not compile. Is this. implicit when you call other methods in a non-static method?

Thank you.

Comment: @BrianRoach Not really.

Comment: @assylias Yes, really. If the OP were taking about a static method calling another static method in the same class ... we wouldn't be having this conversation because that works just fine as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why is that I can call a non-static method in another non-static method without specifying an instance of the class.

Because it's implicitly calling it on `this`:

```
public void foo1() {
    foo2();
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
public void foo1() {
    this.foo2();
}
```

In a static method, there *is* no `this` to implicitly use as the target of the call.

Answer (score 1):

In a non-static context, you are in an instance of a class.  You can call other non-static methods on that class, because you're calling that method on `this`.  In a static context, you have no `this`, so you can't call methods without a particular instance.